# Duda sobre Docker en ubuntu server 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, docker

tengo una pregunta sobre los docker, si descargo un docker que genera un archivo txt y lo genera en cierta dirección, por ejemplo /home/luis/archivo, de que manera puedo sacar ese archivo del docker?
actualmente estoy usando ubuntu server 16.04

Comment: con `scp`por ejemplo

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo con la instucción **docker cp**

1. Supongamos que lanzas el contenedor con el nombre app

```
docker run --rm --name=app myimage/flask
```

Al levantar el contenedor se genera internamente un archivo en la ruta /root/app/archivo.txt

2. Para sacar ese archivo ejecutaría la siguiente instrucción

```
docker cp app:/root/app/archivo.txt archivo.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Para copiar un archivo dentro de un Contenedor
hacia el Servidor.

1. Puedes usar docker cp, se usa de la misma forma que un scp

```
Para un Directorio o Carpeta:
docker cp ID-Contenedor:/Dir/Dir/ /Donde-se-copiara

Para un Archivo:
docker cp ID-Contenedor:/Dir/Dir/archivo.html /Donde-se-copiara
```

Nota: en vez de ID del contenedo, pueder usar el Nombre del Contenedor
que habias asignado en `--name=Nombre`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

`docker cp apache:/var/www/html/index.html .`

Answer (score 0):

Siempre podes usar VOLUME que es básicamente un almacenamiento de forma persistente una vez que el contenedor muere

crea una carpeta del proyecto con un folder dentro

a tu folder lo llamarías por ejemplo datos_persistentes

el dockerfile seria algo así

```
from ubuntu:latest


VOLUME $PWD/datos_persistentes
```

luego, buildearias la imagen (esto en la consola de comandos)

```
docker build -t pruebapersistencia .
```

y por ultimo harias un run (también en la consola de comandos)

```
docker run -it -v $PWD/datos_persistentes:/datos_persistentes --name prueba pruebapersistencia
```

una vez hecho esto, te va a levantar el contenedor, podrías fijarte dentro de ese folder de crear algo ejemplo mkdir prueba

cuando salgas del contenedor eso va a estar creado en tu maquina y no va a desaparecer